# Installing Ldap on windows for ldapsearch cmd

Tags: ldap, openldap

I need to run a ldapsearch command on my windows OS, and currently i'm having quite some trouble understanding how exactly I can do that.
I tried looking up how to set open Ldap on windows but I couldn't find any useful information regarding it.
All the Ldap installers for windows seemed super fishy and not trust worthy.
An installation for linux based OS seems pretty straightforward, but I was wondering if there's a way to be able to exec ldapsearch command on windows.

Is there a way to install Openldap on windows?

Is it possible to run ldapserach command on windows shell?

Thanks in advance,
Gilad.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve what you want, which is using openldap utils commands on Windows, is to install the WSL with the Linux distribution of your choice. For instance Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS version):

- Go to 'Microsoft Store'
- Install the 'Ubuntu 20.04' app
- Launch Powershell
- Launch a shell into the WSL

```
ubuntu2004
```

- Install the openldap utils in the WSL:

```sh
sudo apt install ldap-utils
```

- Then you can easily run any openldap command within the WSL:

```
ldapsearch <your ldapsearch command>
```

Comment: When I read "Go to 'Microsoft Store'" / "Install the 'Ubuntu 20.04' app" I thought you were joking. Turns out this is the only answer that helped me get `ldapsearch` on Win10. Thank you.